# What is option -n for in OpenShift "oc adm policy add-role-to-group" ?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

The OpenShift command line tool (oc) offers a command to add a role to groups of users. The syntax is:

```
oc adm policy add-role-to-group ROLE GROUP [GROUP ...] [options]
```

In a script I found such command with option "-n" but there's no way I can find in the [oc reference documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/cli_reference/index.html) a description of this or other allowed options.

Worse: it seems developers of the oc tool are trying to kid you, as the image shows. [image]

I'm using oc version:

```
oc v3.2.1.13-1-gc2a90e1
kubernetes v1.2.0-36-g4a3f9c5
```

Answer (score 2):

By running the command `oc adm options` you can see that the `-n` option is for the following:
`-n, --namespace='': If present, the namespace scope for this CLI request.`

Comment: Thanks @developercorey. Is there documentation online where these options are described? 
(I hope they fix the usage message on oc anyway.)

Comment: They should be in the CLI Reference here: https://docs.openshift.com/online/cli_reference/index.html

Comment: I had searched the cli reference online with no luck. I think this particular piece of information is not there. Indeed, the following google search shows no results:  `site:docs.openshift.com "namespace scope for this CLI request"`

Answer (score 2):

-n is simply for passing a project name, so your command will run against this project.

e.g. oc add-role-to-group admin groupx -n projectx

will assign admin role to groupx on projectx